# Configuring SSL endpoints for node.js worker roles on Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, https, azure-worker-roles

I've set up a node.js app to run on worker roles (not web roles) on Azure cloud services. Everything was working fine with the standard app running on HTTP.

Now I'm trying to get it running over SSL on HTTPS, and have successfully followed the instructions at http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/common-tasks/enable-ssl-worker-role/ but it has not produced the correct results!

Now when accessing the url over either HTTP or HTTPS the connection times out and nothing is returned.

Is there anything I might be missing or any steps that aren't in the guide linked above?

One thing I did notice in the guide was whether the line...

```
<InputEndpoint name="HttpIn" protocol="tcp" port="443" />
```

... should in fact be *Http***s***In* instead? Though changing this doesn't seem to make a huge amount of difference.

---

Update: here are some of my configuration files

ServiceConfiguration.cloud.cscfg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceConfiguration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" serviceName="*removed*" osFamily="2" osVersion="*" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration">
  <Role name="WorkerRole1">
    <ConfigurationSettings />
    <Instances count="1" />
    <Certificates>
      <Certificate name="certificateName" thumbprint="*removed*" thumbprintAlgorithm="sha1" />
    </Certificates>
  </Role>
</ServiceConfiguration>
```

ServiceDefinition.csdef

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="*removed*" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition">
  <WorkerRole name="WorkerRole1" vmsize="ExtraSmall">
    <Startup>
      <Task commandLine="setup_worker.cmd &gt; log.txt" executionContext="elevated">
        <Environment>
          <Variable name="EMULATED">
            <RoleInstanceValue xpath="/RoleEnvironment/Deployment/@emulated" />
          </Variable>
          <Variable name="RUNTIMEID" value="node" />
          <Variable name="RUNTIMEURL" value="http://az413943.vo.msecnd.net/node/0.8.4.exe" />
        </Environment>
      </Task>
      <Task commandLine="node.cmd .\startup.js" executionContext="elevated" />
    </Startup>
    <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="HttpIn" protocol="http" port="80" />
      <InputEndpoint name="HttpsIn" protocol="https" port="443" certificate="certificateName" />
    </Endpoints>
    <Certificates>
      <Certificate name="certificateName" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" />
    </Certificates>
    <Runtime>
      <Environment>
        <Variable name="PORT">
          <RoleInstanceValue xpath="/RoleEnvironment/CurrentInstance/Endpoints/Endpoint[@name='HttpIn']/@port" />
        </Variable>
        <Variable name="EMULATED">
          <RoleInstanceValue xpath="/RoleEnvironment/Deployment/@emulated" />
        </Variable>
      </Environment>
      <EntryPoint>
        <ProgramEntryPoint commandLine="node.cmd .\server.js" setReadyOnProcessStart="true" />
      </EntryPoint>
    </Runtime>
  </WorkerRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

I have also tried various variations on these (with fewer extra tags and attributes) and nothing seems to work.

Comment: `name` attribute is just a name. The `protocol` and `port` attributes are the important ones, and they are set correctly as per your quoted configuration and in documentation. In order to help you, you need to paste in your question the `.csdef` and `.cscfg` files for your node cloud service. It is possible that you changed something else. The instructions you quote are correct and accurate.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the names. I've updated my post with some configuration files. Initially I didn't change anything else but as it wasn't working I tried adding in a few extra bits (none of which have helped seemingly) until it's what you see pasted above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `protocol` values you provided are `HttpIn` and `HttpsIn`. You shall use these values **only** for ASP.NET Web Roles!! When you run 3rd party web servers on Worker Roles you shall **only** use `tcp` as value for `protocol` attribute!! changing this is the easiest way to make things not working! Could you switch them back to `tcp`, remove the `certificate` attribute from the Https Endpoint and try again?

Also, the default sample app server.js listens to only one port. Which is being passed by the environment value `PORT` defined for the startup task. There you shall reference the HttpsIn endpoint if you want HTTPS traffic. Unfortunately I don't know whether node.js can handle both http AND https traffic with this simple setup.

**UPDATE**

Please use the following `.csconfig` file (replace the content of all `.csconfig` files you see in the folder with the content I provide):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="*removed*" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition">
  <WorkerRole name="WorkerRole1" vmsize="ExtraSmall">
    <Startup>
      <Task commandLine="setup_worker.cmd &gt; log.txt" executionContext="elevated">
        <Environment>
          <Variable name="EMULATED">
            <RoleInstanceValue xpath="/RoleEnvironment/Deployment/@emulated" />
          </Variable>
          <Variable name="RUNTIMEID" value="node" />
          <Variable name="RUNTIMEURL" value="http://az413943.vo.msecnd.net/node/0.8.4.exe" />
        </Environment>
      </Task>
      <Task commandLine="node.cmd .\startup.js" executionContext="elevated" />
    </Startup>
    <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="HttpsIn" protocol="https" port="443" />
    </Endpoints>
    <Certificates>
      <Certificate name="certificateName" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" />
    </Certificates>
    <Runtime>
      <Environment>
        <Variable name="PORT">
          <RoleInstanceValue xpath="/RoleEnvironment/CurrentInstance/Endpoints/Endpoint[@name='HttpsIn']/@port" />
        </Variable>
        <Variable name="EMULATED">
          <RoleInstanceValue xpath="/RoleEnvironment/Deployment/@emulated" />
        </Variable>
      </Environment>
      <EntryPoint>
        <ProgramEntryPoint commandLine="node.cmd .\server.js" setReadyOnProcessStart="true" />
      </EntryPoint>
    </Runtime>
  </WorkerRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

Also, please provide the code in your `server.js` file - at least the first 10 lines where the binding is done. And also after the changes, please execute the following command line and tell us what is the result:

> c:>telnet [your_cloud_service].cloudapp.net 443

And also please confirm that you have the .pfx file in the folder where you are executing the powershell commands.

Comment: Okay, my endpoints section is now just `<InputEndpoint name="HttpsIn" protocol="tcp" port="443" />` again but unfortunately I have the same problem where the connection times out when trying to access over either https or http. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Thank you! All seems to be working now. I'm not sure exactly what fixed it; I had the .pfx file in the WorkerRole1 folder so copied it to the parent folder as well, and I changed the name attribute on this line as you suggested above `<RoleInstanceValue xpath="/RoleEnvironment/CurrentInstance/Endpoints/Endpoint[@name='HttpsIn']/@port" />`